# how to bypass robots.txt with apache nutch 2.2.1

Tags: java, nutch, robots.txt, web-crawler

Can anyone please tell me if there is any way for apache nutch to ignore or bypass robots.txt while crawling. I am using nutch 2.2.1. I found that "RobotRulesParser.java"(full path:-src/plugin/lib-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/ 
RobotRulesParser.java) is responsible for the reading and parsing the robots.txt. Is there any way to modify this file to ignore robots.txt and go on with crawling?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: guys I just want to know this for my own knowledge. I have full respect for robots.txt but what is the harm in having little curiosity . I am a coder after all.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are publicly available and feature high up in the search results on Google. So it won't be "just for your own knowledge" in practice - it will be to the knowledge of everyone that searches for it. Which in this case would be a **Bad Thing**.

Comment: @JonK I will remove this post in that case. But I think you already know that people are already using web crawlers which is designed to ignore robots.txt. please trust me when I say that I have no intention to do these things otherwise I could have simply used one of those crawlers. I am just trying to understand nutch in a better way.

Comment: A Google search on "nutch ignore robots.txt" turns up lots of possibilities. Worst case, just create your own implementation of `org.apache.nutch.protocol.RobotRules` that returns "we are allowed to crawl" for all sites. Seems simple enough to do. I'll leave actual implementation as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. At first, we should respect the robots.txt file if you are crawling any external sites.
   Otherwise you are at risk - your IP banned or worse can be any legal case.
2. If your site is internal and not expose to external world, then you should change the robots.txt file to allow your crawler.
3. If your site is exposed to the Internet and if data is confidential, then you can try out the following option. Because here you cannot take a risk of modifying the robots.txt file since external crawler can use your crawler name and crawl the site.

   In Fetcher.java file:

   ```
   if (!rules.isAllowed(fit.u.toString())) { }
   ```

   This is the block that is responsible for blocking the URLs.  You can play around this code block to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my comment as answer to your question:
But I would like to know which part of mt answer was helpful to you...