# crawling all links of same domain in Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

Can anyone tel me how to crawl all other pages of same domain.

For example i'm feeding a website http://www.techcrunch.com/ in seed.txt.

Following property is added in nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
<value>false</value>
<description>If true, when adding new links to a page, links from
the same host are ignored.  This is an effective way to limit the
size of the link database, keeping only the highest quality
links.
</description>
</property>
```

And following is added in regex-urlfilter.txt

## accept anything else

+.

Note: if i add http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ in seed.txt, I'm able to crawl all other pages but not techcrunch.com's pages though it has got many other pages too.

Please help..?

Comment: Hi,
Could you please share us the logs while crawling?
It will surely tell you why it is not crawling the other website.
I suspect There are too many links available on http://techcrunch.com and while crawling there is one setting number of outlinks to be crawled per page must be less and hence it is not crawling this website.

Answer (score 3):

In `nutch-default.xml` set `db.ignore.external.links` to `true` and 'db.ignore.external.links.mode' to `byDomain`. Like this :

```
<property>
 <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>db.ignore.external.links.mode</name>
 <value>byDomain</value>
</property>
```

By default `db.ignore.external.links.mode` is set to `byHost`. Which means while crawing `http://www.techcrunch.com/` the URL `http://subdomain1.techcrunch.com` will get treated as EXTERNAL and hence will be ignored. But you want `sudomain1` pages to be crawled too - hence keep `db.ignore.external.links.mode` to `byDomain`

No work around required in `regex-urlfilter.txt`. Use `regex-urlfilter.txt` for some complex situation

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong property, first use db.ignore.external.links in nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
 <value>true</value>
 <description>If true, outlinks leading from a page to external hosts
 will be ignored. This will limit your crawl to the host on your seeds file.
 </description>
</property>
```

b) Then you could also use a regex in regex-urlfilter.txt to limit the domains crawled to just techcrunch.

```
+^(http|https)://.*techcrunch.com/
```

**However** I think that your issue is that Nutch obeys the robots.txt file and in this case techcrunch has a Crawl-delay value of 3600!! see [robots.txt](http://techcrunch.com/robots.txt). The default value of fetcher.max.crawl.delay is 30 seconds making Nutch dismiss all the pages from techcrunch.

From fetcher.max.crawl.delay in nutch-default

```
"If the Crawl-Delay in robots.txt is set to greater than this value (in
seconds) then the fetcher will skip this page, generating an error report.
If set to -1 the fetcher will never skip such pages and will wait the
amount of time retrieved from robots.txt Crawl-Delay, however long that
might be."
```

You may want to play with the fetcher.threads.fetch and fetcher.threads.per.queue values to speed up your crawl. You could also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058899/how-to-bypass-robots-txt-with-apache-nutch-2-2-1) and play with the Nutch code.. or you may even want to use a different approach to crawl sites with long crawl delays.

Hope this is useful to you.

Cheers!